# how to use sum method eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

how to get a sum of value in like model in laravel 8

Like Model

```
    public function likeable() {
        return $this->morphTo('likeable', 'likeable_type', 'likeable_id');
    }
```

Post Model

```
    public function likes() {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Like', 'likeable');
    }
```

Main Controller

```
        $posts = Post::withCount('comments')
            ->with('likes')
            ->with('channel')
            ->with('user')
            ->where('posts.hide', '=', '0')
            ->get()
            ->toJson();
```

Like migrate

```
        Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            ...
            $table->integer('value'); // like value
            $table->string('likeable_type', 50);
            $table->integer('likeable_id');
            ...
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the sum of `value` from the `Like` model like this

```
Like::sum('value');
```

If you want to sum only like for a specific likeable you can add more filtering like this

```
Like::where('likeable-type, 'App\Models\Like')->sum('value');
```

Comment: thanks, reply. 
I add sum ( value ) data into each post data 
check My MainController 
I mean
there is getting Channel with specific each post data
and getting User with specific each post data
and wanna get Like with specific each post data !